# Proper means to start an asynchronous helper thread (or callback) in micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I would like to receive real-time callbacks from a service like Google's [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) and then serve these messages with a Micronaut service - i.e., make the messages available to someone who requests a particular endpoint.

In order to achieve this result, I have a `Controller` that owns a Bean. The (singleton) bean is responsible for initiating the relationship with the message service and implements the `ApplicationEventListener<ServiceStartedEvent>` so that i can perform the message service initialization in the `onApplicationEvent()` method for this interface. I annotate this method with `@Async`, with the understanding that this means the bean will execute on the thread pool, which I think is important because this bean is assisted by a static class that implements the [MessageReceiver](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/MessageReceiver.html) interface; this interface is called asynchronously by the PubSub framework to deliver messages that i've subscribed to.

Thus, the Bean drops into a while loop that in order to facilitate the asynchronous callback to the `receiveMessage()` method from the `MessageReceiver` interface.  I've used one of the thread-safe Java [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interfaces so that my while loop is scheduled off the stack when the blocking `take()` method is called (as opposed to a `Thread.sleep()`).

So, my questions are:

1. is this the correct method for handling asynchronous callbacks or does this consume resources that Micronaut normally would use - i.e., is it ok that `onApplicationEvent()` never "returns"?  (the code below works, but i have not profiled it)
2. Should the bean own/use the `TaskScheduler` or `ExecutorService` to create this behavior instead, or is that what `@Async` does?  (i've read the guides, and the `TaskScheduler` seems like an option)
3. Does this methodology scale - i.e., if I have multiple topics that I am subscribed to, should there be a Bean per message topic?

Here is the bean code, which works fine on my test server:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;

import io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventListener;
import io.micronaut.discovery.event.ServiceStartedEvent;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.annotation.Async;

@Singleton
public class PubsubManager implements ApplicationEventListener<ServiceStartedEvent> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubsubManager.class);
    // use the default project id
    private static final String PROJECT_ID = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();
    private static final BlockingQueue<PubsubMessage> messages = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<PubsubMessage> latestMessages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    private String subscriptionId = "sub1";
    private Subscriber subscriber = null;

    static class PubsubReceiver implements MessageReceiver {
        @Override
        public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
            log.info("received message id: " + message.getMessageId());
            latestMessages.add(message);
            //local queue for routing to db
            messages.offer(message);
            consumer.ack();
        }
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ServiceStartedEvent event) {
        log.info("Loading pubsub at startup");
        ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(PROJECT_ID, subscriptionId);
        // create a subscriber bound to the asynchronous message receiver
        subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, new PubsubReceiver()).build();
        subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
        log.info("started pubsub");
        // Continue to listen to messages
        try {
            while (true) {
                PubsubMessage message = messages.take();//this schedules us off stack
                log.info("Message Id: " + message.getMessageId());
                log.info("Data: " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
                log.info("as string: " + message.toString());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (subscriber != null) {
                subscriber.stopAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<PubsubMessage> getLatestMessages() {
        return latestMessages;
    }

}
```

Comment: Each one of these type beans would be controlling 1 thread from the scheduler pool, so this wouldn't work if the number of beans increased close to the amount of threads configured for the pool. You should setup a new thread pool for this use case

Comment: @JamesKleeh ok, to clarify you're referring to the "caching I/O thread pool", which uses the [ExecutorConfiguration](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/scheduling/executor/ExecutorConfiguration.html)?